# How to write a list of files in Java

Tags: java, list, file, fileoutputstream

I have a class in Java which write a file using FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream. This is working fine but my intention is that I want to write any number of files in java not just one.  Here is my code written in Java

```
public class FileToBeTaken{


 public void fileBack(byte [] output) {

     FileOutputStream fop = null;
     BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        File file;


        try {       
            file= new File("/Users/user/Desktop/newfile.txt");

            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fop);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }



            bos.write(output);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here `fileBack` method is called from another class inside a for loop n times. so for each time I need to write a new file onto my desktop as my code is I just take only the file for the last iteration. Also I should mention that for each iteration as parameter to this class is send one array of bytes which is taken by "byte [] output

Comment: Can you please provide a runnale example?

Comment: clearly you already understand that you can pass parameters to a function, since you use that for the content of a file. I don't understand what prevents you from passing the file name as a parameter too.

Comment: @njzk2 because i want to create these file names inside this class i wrote above so i do not really understand how can i pass it as a parameter to my other class

Answer (score 2):

Change
`public void fileBack(byte [] output) {`

to

`public void fileBack(String fileName, byte [] output) {`

Then change where you call method fileBack in your other class by providing the file name there. ie

```
byte output[] = //You already provide this byte array

String fileName = "/Users/user/Desktop/newfile.txt"

fileBack(fileName, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking in the file path `..newfile.txt` and making it into a parameter for the function. Then you can put a for loop in `main` or whoever is instantiating this object and call it `n` times. Does that help at all?

Comment: could you please write down the code because i do not understand the part you said "making it into a parameter for the function"

Comment: @alex10 , i think  @ares means you have to change method signature from `public void fileBack( byte [] output ) {` to this `public void fileBack(String fileName, byte [] output) {`, and send path of `newfile.txt` to use it in `fileBack` method.

Answer (score 0):

just add one static and private integer field inside `FileToBeTaken` class.

```
private static int index=0;
```

so there is no need to pass name of file to this class as you mentioned in question comments.

> because i want to create these file names inside this class i wrote above

then use it in `fileBack` method and each time incremet it once in that method.

here is the changes on your code:

```
public class FileToBeTaken {

    // index or number of new file, also number of all written files
    // because it increments each time you call fileBack method.
    private static int index = 0;

    public void fileBack(byte[] output) {

        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        File file;

        try {

            // use user_dir to place files on desktop, 
            // even on other machines which have other names except user.
            String user_dir = System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/");

            // use index to create name of file.
            file = new File(user_dir+"/Desktop/newfile_" + (index++) + ".txt");

            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fop);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            bos.write(output);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

            System.out.println("Done - "+file.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new FileToBeTaken().fileBack("some text".getBytes());
}
```

the output:

```
Done - newfile_0.txt
Done - newfile_1.txt
Done - newfile_2.txt
Done - newfile_3.txt
Done - newfile_4.txt
Done - newfile_5.txt
Done - newfile_6.txt
Done - newfile_7.txt
Done - newfile_8.txt
Done - newfile_9.txt
```

Comment: i do not know how to thank you. it was really helpful. Thnx a lot man and god bless you

Comment: @alex10 your welcome, if you think my answer is useful, just Up vote it and share it with others :) , God bless you too.